# Does one choose SOAP vs REST based on the data?

Tags: javascript, rest, wcf, soap, wcf-data-services

I've read all the links regarding `WCF` `SOAP` and `REST` services, so I understand the theory behind it. Please bear with me because the question may be difficult to understand.

We have several `javascript` maps that read `GeoJSON` data from several `WCF` services that I created. These are `REST` services because they're returning JSON.

The only reason they return JSON (which make them `REST`) is because that's the format that the maps read. The maps do not read `XML`.

From my point-of-view, the only factor I took into consideration was the type of data the map consumes (`JSON`) and thus created the service. These services happen to be REST.

In other words, I never once asked myself ***Hmmm... should it be REST or SOAP?***. I simply said ***I need to create a service that returns JSON so the maps work. And BTW, it's REST.***.

Is that how one selects if the architecture used is `SOAP` or `REST`?